# paypal express checkout dont work with sandbox

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I try to integrate paypal express checkout using wizard https://devtools-paypal.com/integrationwizard/

All right if Iam using it with real account, but if I enter sandbox account credentials script show this with no error: "SetExpressCheckout API call failed. Error Message: Error Code: "

I have checked what returns my script's $resArray. I's OK:

> Array ( [TOKEN] => EC-2FP9406707909490N [TIMESTAMP] => 2016-01-27T14:52:37Z [CORRELATIONID] => b6329a695bbf3 [ACK] => Success [VERSION] => 93 [BUILD] => 18308778 )

```
   $resArray = CallShortcutExpressCheckout ($paymentAmount, $currencyCodeType, $paymentType, $returnURL, $cancelURL);
    $ack = strtoupper($resArray["ACK"]);
    if($ack=="SUCCESS" || $ack=="SUCCESSWITHWARNING")
    {
        RedirectToPayPal ( $resArray["TOKEN"] );
    } 
    else  
    {
        $ErrorCode = urldecode($resArray["L_ERRORCODE0"]);
        $ErrorShortMsg = urldecode($resArray["L_SHORTMESSAGE0"]);
        $ErrorLongMsg = urldecode($resArray["L_LONGMESSAGE0"]);
        $ErrorSeverityCode = urldecode($resArray["L_SEVERITYCODE0"]);

        echo "SetExpressCheckout API call failed. ";
        echo "Detailed Error Message: " . $ErrorLongMsg;
        echo "Short Error Message: " . $ErrorShortMsg;
        echo "Error Code: " . $ErrorCode;
        echo "Error Severity Code: " . $ErrorSeverityCode;
    }
```

But if I replace real to sandbox credetials $resArray return empty array.

> Array ( ) SetExpressCheckout API call failed. Detailed Error Message:
>   Short Error Message: Error Code: Error Severity Code:

what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Have to check your SSL certification on API call time.
Paypal recently change there API. Now it Experiment in sandbox. After june,2016 sandbox and live both credential are not work without SSL. For details Check : https://devblog.paypal.com/upcoming-security-changes-notice/#tls

Comment: I asked all and finally found one who answered my question. thank you so much. :)